# VBSCRIPT Split String

Tags: vbscript, split

How can I split a string using vbscript?

```
Dim personal_number
Dim personal_prefix

person_prefix = Split(personal_number, 4)
```

I want to split person_prefix and grab the first four characters. Is this the correct approach because it seems to return the entire string on document.write.

Comment: What if I want to grab '25' out of '10253940'. The numbers between 10 and 3940?

Comment: I solved it by first doing a person_prefix = Left(personal_number, X) and then another Left or Right to grab what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return the first four characters use `person_prefix = Left(personal_number, 4)` instead.

(String splitting breaks up a string into an array using a supplied delimiter: not relevant in your case).